# Uppercase column in tabular

Tags: tables, columns, capitalization

I need one column of my table to be uppercased. 
My code which does not work as I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c>{\MakeUppercase}c}
    a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` takes an argument. Compare by replacing `\MakeUppercase` with `\sffamily` and `\textsf`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our own Martin Scharrer's `collcell` package is ideal for this sort of thing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\collectcell\MakeUppercase}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cU}
    a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use a macro like `\MakeUpperCase` with no `{}` then it will take the first token following as argument but in this case that token is not `b` but:

```
\MakeUppercase #1->\protect \MakeUppercase  {#1}
#1<-\ignorespaces
```

the `\ignorespaces` token that LaTeX places at the front of each cell so that white space after `&` is ignored.

Comment: Very nice complement to Alan's solution, responding to the "What's the problem?" question.